# how can I change values inside a variable?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am creating a procedure that is reading from a table called tab with column( col1 ).
The col1 contain such data:

```
Select test from dual.
```

I have in the procedure :

```
select col1 into var1 from tab
```

so the data is in the var1 , how can I change the word test in the var1 ?

I want var1 contain such data : select changed from dual.

I know I can you use substr , is there another way ?

Edit.
var1 is like this . Var1 = ' select test from dual'

I want to change the value of var1 to become like this

var1 = 'select CHANGED from dual'

because later on I want to insert var1 into another table.

Comment: You don't have to use a select statement.  You just assign the value to the variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean you want to assign the variable a new value?  If so just use an assignment statement:

```
var1 := 'changed';
```

Answer (score 0):

it will be var1 := 'select CHANGED from dual';

or

select changed into var1 from dual;

or

still your question is not clear